# OpenCV Python - cv2 Module not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

Even though I believe I have installed correctly OpenCV, I cannot overcome the following problem. When I start a new python project from IDLE (2.7) the cv2 module is imported successfully. If I close IDLE and try to run the .py file, an error message is displayed that says "ImportError: No module named cv2". Then if I create a clean project through IDLE it works until I close it. What could be the problem?

P.S. I am using Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.1, but tried also with 2.4.13 on Windows 10.

Comment: You might need to have the CV file within the same directory as the `.py` file. Or the CV file isn't imported into the project correctly.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reinstall it by `sudo apt-get install python-opencv`,
But first you may check out something you might be skipping.
Make sure the script you are running on the terminal is on the same python version/ location as on IDLE. 
Maybe your IDLE is running on a different interpreter(different location).
Open IDLE and check the path of cv2 module by `cv2.__file__`.
Or you can check the executables path by `sys.path`. 
Then check the executable python path by running the script from the terminal, it must be same or else you need to explicitly set the `PYTHONPATH` to executable path shown in IDLE.

Edit: 
According to the comments the problem you are facing is with the execution path,  add the idle execution path to the environment variable `path` - on Windows.  You can do it on the go by

`SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\python27` on cmd
Change the path to your context (of the IDLE).

Comment: I actually forgot to mention that the system runs Windows 10. But I did what you proposed and it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Check the execution path doing `sys.path`on IDLE and then on cmd(by opening `python` interpreter @cmd),  is it same?

Comment: You are actually completely right! Another software that I use comes with a Python installation and I guess it causes a conflict. How can I solve it?

Comment: Check the executable path on IDLE ..  On Windows it would be something like `c:\python2x` or whatever..  You need to set the same path as environment variable(My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables)   i.e. `PYTHONPATH` to the same.

Comment: Instead of adding the path to the variable `PYTHONPATH` add it to `path`